# Facebook Connect - Need email and userlikes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to get the permissions for my facebook connection. Here's what I have:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'myID', // App ID
        channelUrl : 'myChannel', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
        oauth      : true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {testAPI();} 
        if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});} 
        else { FB.login(function(response) {}, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});}
    });
};

(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

When I hit my login button it asks:

> MyApp would like to access your public profile and friend list.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Does authResponseChange fire? First thing I would check is to put some console.log inside that function(response) and also right before FB.login to make sure they are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the scope you are not giving permissions to the app. You are only telling that permissions that your app will need.
When you click in the login button for the first time, that dialog saying that "MyApp would like to access your public profile and friend list." appear. You need to confirm that you grant that permissions to your app by clicking in the ok button or similar in that dialog.

You should not need to to this again unless you change your application id or key or you manually revoke the authorization for that app in the facebook settings.